# How to save automatically specific content of a website to my Mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone tell me how to save automatically specific content of a website (when the websites updates) to my mysql database using php. I searched net but i didnt find  any useful sites. I have found a similar question from this forum  [How can I save content from another website to my database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954002/how-can-i-save-content-from-another-website-to-my-database)  but its vague. can any one give me a simple script or example (if possible explain) about it . I have a little experience in php and mysql.

advance thanks for your help

Comment: Use crontab/daemon to execute the script regularly, use curl or `file_get_contents` (or similar) to get the content (raw html), then put it in a database. Obviously, this won't follow the links/resources found in the html

Comment: Is it your website? Do they have an API/RSS feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways. I'd avoid `file_get_contents()` if I were you. Try [cURL](http://www.php.net/curl).

If you want a wrapper for cURL, check out the REST client of Spoon Library. You can make easy GET requests with it:
[SpoonRESTClient::execute($url, $parameters)](https://github.com/Spoon/library/blob/master/spoon/rest/client.php)